# Empty data after asfreq in Pandas DataReader

Tags: python, pandas

I am fetching data using pandas_datareader

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as dr

start = datetime.datetime(2012, 7, 31)
end = datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 30)

aapl = dr.DataReader('WIKI/AAPL', 'quandl', start, end)
```

And I am following the [official pandas tutorials](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html) for Time Series and trying to use the `asfreq` method on the data I have.

Here is some more information on my dataframe `aapl`

```
print(type(aapl.index))
# <class 'pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex'>
print(len(aapl['AdjClose']))
# 1238
print(aapl.index[0:5])
# DatetimeIndex(['2017-06-30', '2017-06-29', '2017-06-28', '2017-06-27', '2017-06-26'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Date', freq=None)
```

The issue I am having is, when I try `asfreq` I seem to lose all data:

```
print(aapl.asfreq('BM')['AdjClose'])
# Series([], Freq: BM, Name: AdjClose, dtype: float64)
```

What am I overlooking here?

Comment: What is BM? i have a code like that and this is what appears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data is in reversed order, try:

```
aaplR = aapl[::-1]
aaplR.asfreq('BM')['AdjClose']
```